# head cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method insert(LinkedList, String) in the type Linkedlist is not applicable for the arguments (LinkedList, int)

at uts3.Linkedlist.main(Linkedlist.java:61)
```

Here's the code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Linkedlist {
        
    Node head;
    
    static int sum = 0;
    
    static class Node{
        String nama;
        Node next;
        
        Node(String n){
            nama = n;
            next = null;
        }
    }
    
    public static LinkedList insert(LinkedList list, String nama) {
        
        Node new_node = new Node(nama);
        new_node.next = null;
        
        if (list.head == null) {
            list.head = new_node;
        }
        else {
            Node last = list.head;
            while (last.next != null) {
                last = last.next;
            }
            last.next = new_node;
        }
        return list;
    }
    
    public static void printList(LinkedList list) {
        Node currNode = list.head;
        System.out.print("\nLinkedList: ");
        
        while (currNode != null) {
        System.out.print(currNode.nama + "");
        currNode = currNode.next;
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        Node head = null;
        Scanner x = new Scanner( System.in );
        
        System.out.println("Masukan 10 Nama");
        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            int a = x.nextInt();
            list = insert(list, a);
        }
        printList(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: The very first thing I'd suggest is that you don't try to run code that doesn't yet compile. We don't know what your environment is, but I'd *expect* you to be able to see all the compilation errors before you try to run... don't even *attempt* to run the code until it compiles correctly.

Comment: Next, the error message you've reported in your title isn't the error message in the body of the question. The error message in the body of the question seems reasonably clear - when you call `insert(LinkedList list, String name)` with an *integer* value for the second argument, what do you expect the value of the parameter to be?

Comment: Oh my bad. I didn't notice if the question hadn't been changed.

Comment: and I expect string.

Comment: So how are you expecting the `int` to be converted to a `String`, and where do you believe you've expressed that conversion in code? (Would you expect `String x = 10;` to compile?)

Answer (score 0):

it says that you have created a method that get String as a parameter, and you are passing int:

Your method definition:

```java
  public static LinkedList insert(LinkedList list, String nama)
```

Expects String, and here:

```
 System.out.println("Masukan 10 Nama");
        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            int a = x.nextInt();
            list = insert(list, a);
        }
```

You are passing int.
Solution: Change method's signature, or change the data passed in the loop.

Regarding The title: first check typo in you code.
You are passing LinkedList object, not Linkedlist to the insert method.

Comment: "Change method's signature" nope, that would break the call to `Node`'s constructor in turn.

Comment: In that case try to use
`list = insert(list, String.valueOf(a));`

Answer (score 0):

I will not post the correct code, but the problem in your code is ,

Your class name is `Linkedlist` but you are creating an instance of `LinkedList` which is a property of `java.util.LinkedList`

Solution:

1. Remove import statement `import java.util.LinkedList` and re-modify code again and compile at the end.

+1:

You have another problem with method signature of `insert` method.